# Textfile search from GUI

Tags: java, swing, search, text-files

Ok so i have made a search function using scanner in console, but i would now like to create a search function from my GUI. When text is entered into a `JTextField`and `JButton` is clicked i would like a method which would search my text file line by line until it finds the the searched for criteria and prints it into a `JOptionPane`.

Data in text file is formatted as follows:

what would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have the search method, so add an action listener to your button, that will call your method, something like:

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String whatToSearch = myTextField.getText();
        String result = yourSearchMethod(whatToSearch);
        // use the fitting method of JOptionPane to display the result
    }
}
```

Seeing your update, you better split the search function, so it will receive the search criteria as an input, something like:

```
public class SearchProp {
     public String getSearchCriteria()
     {
            Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please enter your Search: ");
            input = user.next();
     }

     public void Search(String input) throws FileNotFoundException{
        try{
            String details, id, line;
            int count;
            Scanner housenumber = new Scanner(new File("writeto.txt"));
            while(housenumber.hasNext())
            {
                id = housenumber.next();
                line = housenumber.nextLine();
                if(input.equals(id))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,id + line );
                    break;
                }
                if(!housenumber.hasNext())      
                     System.out.println("No Properties with this criteria");
            }
       }

       catch(IOException e)
       {
            System.out.print("File failure");
       }
   }
}
```

Now, when you run it from console, you first call the `getSearchCriteria` and then `Search`. The input of `Search` is the return value of `getSearchCriteria`. In your GUI you only need to call search (with the text from the JTextField as an input).

Comment: i understand the ActionListener you have suggested but my current search class relies on a scanner, i have posted my current search method in my edited question if you'd have chance to have a look

Comment: I saw, see my update, and separate the input and actual search to different methods, that will give you more flexibility, as you need now.

Comment: Gonna have to give this a break, my heads battered just trying to find how to separate to two methods.

Comment: Not my usual approach, but I will give you an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes a lot more sense. i had just missed a few little bits out.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know..

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String whatToSearch = myTextField.getText();
        String result = yourSearchMethod(whatToSearch);
        // use the fitting method of JOptionPane to display the result
    }
}
```